# How do I make this little twitching go away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

So I have an update method in my **SpriteKit game project**, in which according to the leaders following direction the position of other following characters is decided:

```
-(void) update {

if (_followingEnabled == YES || _isLeader == YES) {

switch (currentDirection) {
    case up:
        self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y + speed);
        // making a line of characters
        if (self.position.x < _idealX && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x + 1, self.position.y);
        } else if (self.position.x > _idealX && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x - 1, self.position.y);
        }
        break;
    case down:
        self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y - speed);
        // making a line of characters
        if (self.position.x < _idealX && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x + 1, self.position.y);
        } else if (self.position.x > _idealX && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x - 1, self.position.y);
        }
        break;
    case left:
        self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x - speed, self.position.y);
        // making a line of characters
        if (self.position.y < _idealY && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y + 1);
        } else if (self.position.y < _idealY && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y - 1);
        }
        break;
    case right:
        self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x + speed, self.position.y);
        // making a line of characters
        if (self.position.y < _idealY && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y + 1);
        } else if (self.position.y < _idealY && _isLeader == NO) {
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x, self.position.y - 1);
        }
        break;
    case noDirection:
        // in case you want to do something for noDirection
        break;
    default:
        break;
} // switch (currentDirection) {

} // if (_followingEnabled == YES && _isLeader == YES) {

}
```

`_idealX` and `_idealY` are integers passed from the leader's position (I did set them up as properties..) and the position of my other characters that are following him is float (correct me if I'm wrong)

**my theory:**

Therefore, when I add or subtract 1, the position of my characters(float) will never be equal to `_idealX / _idealY(int)` and the statements will run over and over, which causes this little "twitching" or "shaking" on the Y/X axis (adding and subtracting the 1).

So you would understand and visualise this better, I made a screenshot of how it looks like (the 2 characters behind him(Leader) twitch when moving..):

[image]

**HOW DO I FIX THIS SO THE FOLLOWERS DON'T "TWITCH" or "SHAKE" behind the leader???**

Comment: Depends on whether it's essential tremor or benign fasciculation syndrome.

Comment: its just 1 pixel to left and 1 to right or up and down, depending on the direction, 20 times per second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember the exact calculations anymore but a general method is to try and be sure that things are aligned to the pixel grid for display.

```
x = floorf(x+0.5)
```

You will need an actual position and a drawing position since if you use the floored values things won't work as intended at low speeds.

Comment: thank you @0xFADE, it turns out they obj-C has a function for rounding up floats so all I had to do is:

self.position = CGPointMake (round(self.position.x) + 1, self.position.y);

and likewise for other directions...

Answer (score 0):

You don't let them move in more than one direction at a time. Maybe diagonal moves should be an option?